# How do I make a raspberry pi raspbian application?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am struggling on how to make a Raspberry Pi app for Raspbian (On a raspberry pi). I have searched and searched for hours but I still can't find out how to make one. There are apps that I can use but I cannot install them. Should I use python??... Please help me!!...

I found a few visual editors like XOJO, I am knew to "RASPBERRY PI" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a bare machine you can cover it with anything you want. It's basically Lightweight Linux distro which we install mostly on the PI. Can support wide range of applications but IOT related products are more often developed using PI. If this is the case you can start here using android also.

https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi